# TFS Folder Difference -> View Target bug?

Tags: tfs

Is this a bug in TFS 2010? Has anyone else come across this? Am I doing something wrong?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Right click on a folder in the Source Control Explorer and choose View History.
2. Right click a changeset and choose Compare…
3. For the Target Path, pick another (more recent) changeset and press OK.
4. In the resultant Folder Differences window, right-click on a file with differences and select Compare Files. Note the differences, and leave the compare tool open for future reference.
5. Back in the Folder Differences window, right click the same file and choose View. Choose the Source and confirm that you do indeed view the source version. (Cross-check with the compare tool left open in step 4.)
6. Back in the Folder Differences window, right click the same file and choose View. Choose the Target.

Expected result: to see the target version of the file.

Actual result: I get the source version of the file again.

Does anyone else get this?

Comment: Could you do a set of screenshots or a short youtube on this so that we see exactly what you're doing. I can't wrap it around in my head by just reading the description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in VS 2010 and I can reproduce it using the RTM and SP1 versions.  I can also confirm that this has been fixed in VS 2012 which is currently in Beta.  As a workaround, when you right click on the item, select View History.  This will show you the history of the file and from there you can right-click on the version you are interested and select "View".

Sorry about the inconvenience.

-Taylor, TFS Version Control Development Lead